# On pressing the back key activity is not going back

Tags: java, android, back-button

i am getting a strange problem.

On pressing the back key activity is not going back.
in logcat it is showing

```
04-15 19:24:09.063: V/Activity(23041): Tracking Key Up, activity is resumed: false
```

here is my code for the activity

```
package com.sandy.letsfixthat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;


public class Slider extends Activity {
    TabSpec beginer,inter,dev;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.slider);
        TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);

        // state will be bundle your activity state which you
        // get in onCreate
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
        th.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
        //tab for beginner
        beginer = th.newTabSpec("Begin");
        beginer.setIndicator("Beginner");
        Intent begin = new Intent(this, Beginner.class);
        beginer.setContent(begin);
        th.addTab(beginer);

        //tab for intermediate
        inter = th.newTabSpec("Inter");
        inter.setIndicator("Intermediate");
        Intent Intermediate = new Intent(this, Intermediate.class);
        inter.setContent(Intermediate);
        th.addTab(inter);

        //tab for developers
        dev = th.newTabSpec("Devel");
        dev.setIndicator("Other");
        Intent develop = new Intent(this, Developer.class);
        dev.setContent(develop);
        th.addTab(dev);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;

  /*    case R.id.setting:
            Intent setting = new Intent (this,Settings.class);
            startActivity(setting);
            break;                          */
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // your code.
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

code of MainActivity

```
package com.sandy.letsfixthat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button go;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bgo);
        go.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.bgo:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("NOTE:- this is an initial release. MORE TUTORIAL COMING IN NEXT UPDATE")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do things
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Slider.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

When I open this slider activity and press back button, nothing happens.
What it should do on back button press is EXIT THE APP.

Comment: why did you call finish() in your onPause()?

Comment: to pause the activity when i moved to some other activity

Comment: this will not pause it, it will end it. For example if your app is put in the background, there will be no coming back, as it will be destroyed.

Comment: so what it should be like??

Comment: the OS handles the pause of the activity, you don't have to override the method unless you want to do something in it, like save preferences, write to database,... . Is your application exiting when using the exit option in the menu you declared?

Comment: let me clear my question.
i have a button on main activity and by clicking on that button i moved to my this Slider activity.
now the exit button from menu is working fine.
but when i press back button in slider activity it is doing nothing.

Comment: well, in the activity stack the normal behaviour would be to return to the main activity on back pressed. Isn't that happening either?

Comment: no...when i press back button nothing happens. only phone is vibrating due to press of button but no effect on activity.
logcat is there in the question.

Comment: It's possible that it tries to navigate back to your main activity, which was destroyed in its onPause() because of your finish() calling. Try removing finish() from onPause()

Comment: i removed onPause method from both my MainActivity and Slider class. but still same error on back key press :(

Comment: And you can't see anything else relevant in the log? Try debugging the activity. Does it reach to its onPause() method? Try overriding onBackPressed and see if it's called when pressing the back button.

Comment: nothing happening still the same problem

Comment: check your back key of the device .. if this is the whole code you wrote then may be there is some problem in the back key..... and if there is some other codes too that you havent pasted then paste those here

Comment: back key is working properly and pasting the code of main activity also..

EDITED THE QUESTION

Answer (score 2):

just add this Line:

```
mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume();
```

worked for me!

Comment: It might be useful if You could provide more decriptive answer (e.g. explain why suggested fix resolves the issue).

Comment: i don't really know how it resolves the issue but when working around with this problem i find this "dispatchResume() - Called by the container activity in its onResume() so that LocalActivityManager can perform the corresponding action on the activities it holds." so maybe the LocalActivityManager need to call this to 'Manage' the activity. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button function with:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
  finish(); 
}
```

so it will finish your app.
Just keep in mind that this is not the best solution and you should not use finish () in the on pause method.

Comment: The standard behaviour is to finish the activity when the back button is pressed. You don't need to override this method to get the standard behaviour. This solution isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you shouldn't need to do anything for the back button to terminate your activity. What you need to do is *not* override **onBackButtonPressed()** or **onKeyDown()**. Or if you do override **onKeyDown()**, then don't do anything for keycode KEYCODE_BACK other than return false.

Note that this only terminates the *activity*, not the *application*. If you want to exit the entire application, then it's a little trickier. Let us know if that's what you wanted to do, and I'll expand on this answer.